# I need help looping an index/match that is inside an if statement using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops, excel-formula

I am trying to create a VBA macro to fill in cells that are empty in a range ("INV_Nums") without overwriting the cell if it contains data already.  In order to accomplish this I am trying to use an if statement to check if the cell in question is blank...if it is not, then I want the loop to continue on to the next cell, however if it IS blank then I want to input the index(__,(match()) function into the cell.

I keep getting a "compile error: mismatch" on the True statement but I'm at a loss as to why my synatax would be wrong.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim Rng As Range
Dim ARwkb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ARwks As Excel.Worksheet
Dim Samwkb As Excel.Workbook
Dim Samwks As Excel.Worksheet

Set Samwkb = Excel.Workbooks("Samples - one sheet")
Set Samwks = Samwkb.Worksheets("samples shipment")
Set ARwkb = Excel.Workbooks("AR balance.xlsx")
Set ARwks = ARwkb.Worksheets("Total Trading")
Set Rng = Samwkb.Range("INV_Nums")

For i = 6 To Rng.Rows.Count + 6

If Range("AAi") = "" Is True Then
    Range("AAi").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=INDEX('AR balance.xlsx'!AR_Invoice_Nums,MATCH(RC[-21],'AR 
balance.xlsx'!AR_PL_Nums,0))"
        End If
    Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in how you are identifying the range and administering the criteria.

```
For i = 6 To Rng.Rows.Count + 6
    If IsEmpty(Range("AA" & i)) Then
        Range("AA" & i).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=INDEX('AR balance.xlsx'!AR_Invoice_Nums, MATCH(RC[-21],'AR balance.xlsx'!AR_PL_Nums, 0))"
    End If
Next i
```

The .SpecialCells method can quickly determine the blank cells and an xlR1C1 formula can be used to insert all of the formulas at once..

```
...
with Samwkb.Range("INV_Nums")
    .specialcells(xlcelltypeblanks).FormulaR1C1 = _
      "=INDEX('AR balance.xlsx'!AR_Invoice_Nums, MATCH(RC[-21],'AR balance.xlsx'!AR_PL_Nums, 0))"
end with
...
```